# Clean/Redirect URL after adding products to cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

Since the latest releases of elementor and woocommerce i seem to be having a problem i cant fix.

Basically im adding multiple products to cart by url manipulation with data coming from a form calculator. This worked well for over a year and now suddenly doesnt.

*1. Description of the function*

When i press the button on the calculator page, it calculates the values which are then parsed into a field and added to the current url.

`document.location.href='?add-to-cart='  +fieldname51+':'+fieldname15+',' +fieldname52+':'+fieldname16+',' +fieldname53+':'+fieldname17+',' , ....`

example of the data of such field where following applies: `<productid1>:<product quantitiy1> , <productid2>:<product quantitiy2> , ...`

```
?add-to-cart=11439:4,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,11469:2,0:0,0:0,0:0,5213:1,11425:1,5246:1,5275:2,5304:2,5329:6,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,11705:6
```

I've used and adapted some code snippets to add multiple product variations to cart through url in woocommerce and added it to my functions.php file in wordpress:

```
/** ADD PRODUCTS THROUGH URL CODE **/


function webroom_add_multiple_products_to_cart( $url = false ) {
    // Make sure WC is installed, and add-to-cart qauery arg exists, and contains at least one comma.
    if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Form_Handler' ) || empty( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] ) || false === strpos( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'], ',' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Remove WooCommerce's hook, as it's useless (doesn't handle multiple products).
    remove_action( 'wp_loaded', array( 'WC_Form_Handler', 'add_to_cart_action' ), 20 );

    $product_ids = explode( ',', $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] );
    $count       = count( $product_ids );
    $number      = 0;

    foreach ( $product_ids as $id_and_quantity ) {
        // Check for quantities defined in curie notation (<product_id>:<product_quantity>)
        
        $id_and_quantity = explode( ':', $id_and_quantity );
        $product_id = $id_and_quantity[0];

        $_REQUEST['quantity'] = ! empty( $id_and_quantity[1] ) ? absint( $id_and_quantity[1] ) : 1;

        if ( ++$number === $count ) {
            // Ok, final item, let's send it back to woocommerce's add_to_cart_action method for handling.
            $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] = $product_id;

            return WC_Form_Handler::add_to_cart_action( $url );
        }

        $product_id        = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint( $product_id ) );
        $was_added_to_cart = false;
        $adding_to_cart    = wc_get_product( $product_id );

        if ( ! $adding_to_cart ) {
            continue;
        }

        $add_to_cart_handler = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_handler', $adding_to_cart->get_type(), $adding_to_cart );

        // Variable product handling
        if ( 'variable' === $add_to_cart_handler ) {
            woo_hack_invoke_private_method( 'WC_Form_Handler', 'add_to_cart_handler_variable', $product_id );

        // Grouped Products
        } elseif ( 'grouped' === $add_to_cart_handler ) {
            woo_hack_invoke_private_method( 'WC_Form_Handler', 'add_to_cart_handler_grouped', $product_id );

        // Custom Handler
        } elseif ( has_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_handler_' . $add_to_cart_handler ) ){
            do_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_handler_' . $add_to_cart_handler, $url );

        // Simple Products
        } else {
            woo_hack_invoke_private_method( 'WC_Form_Handler', 'add_to_cart_handler_simple', $product_id );
        }
    }
}

// Fire before the WC_Form_Handler::add_to_cart_action callback.
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'webroom_add_multiple_products_to_cart', 15 );


/**
 * Invoke class private method
 *
 * @since   0.1.0
 *
 * @param   string $class_name
 * @param   string $methodName
 *
 * @return  mixed
 */
function woo_hack_invoke_private_method( $class_name, $methodName ) {
    if ( version_compare( phpversion(), '5.3', '<' ) ) {
        throw new Exception( 'PHP version does not support ReflectionClass::setAccessible()', __LINE__ );
    }

    $args = func_get_args();
    unset( $args[0], $args[1] );
    $reflection = new ReflectionClass( $class_name );
    $method = $reflection->getMethod( $methodName );
    $method->setAccessible( true );

    //$args = array_merge( array( $class_name ), $args );
    $args = array_merge( array( $reflection ), $args );
    return call_user_func_array( array( $method, 'invoke' ), $args );
    
}
```

*2. The problem*

Now for some reason when pressing the calculation button, it indeed does as expected and adds said products to cart, however **the field parameters stay stuck in the url**.

What happens is as soon as you press another link on the website, or the cart or whatever, it "refreshes" the page and **parses the same field values again, causing the cart to have  twice the amount of products than intended**.

*3. Tried the following*

i've tried redirecting the field data after calculation with `window.location.replace`  but it redirects before it has time to calculate and add the products to cart

`setTimeout(function(){window.location.replace("url or url/fielddata");},3000);` also didnt work when added to an onclick event from the calculation button, because then it no longer sees the field data or makes the calculations, adding nothing to cart

attempts to "remove the parametes" after clicking failed and caused the same issues as above.

*4. Goal*

The goal is either to clean the URL after pressing the button and adding products to cart or to redirect to the basket or any custom URL without parsing the existing parameters from the field data again. either solution would work but maybe it is not possible to do.