# WooCommerce - when adding to cart via custom query string and logging in all quantities get re-added to the cart

Tags: woocommerce

I refer to [Adding multiple items to WooCommerce cart at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42570982/adding-multiple-items-to-woocommerce-cart-at-once/60012299#60012299).

Unfortunately, I cannot comment so i have to create a new thread.

When using any of the custom code in the thread above when logged out they work fine (e.g. https://www.mysite/checkout?add-to-cart=77499,58129:2,50578:3&coupon_code=IndustryMemberPrice

However, when logging in (e.g. the person checking out already has an account) after having added to cart when logged out, all the quantities get added to the cart again.

So i end up with
77499 -> cannot add another of these to the cart (because i have set only 1 per order)
58129: 4
50578: 6

I have looked and [only seem to find one person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71397276/clean-redirect-url-after-adding-products-to-cart/75745144?noredirect=1#comment133619351_75745144) who has a similar issue.

I believe it is because the query string just auto reloads on checkout.

Would appreciate any advice.